# Can't configure and correctly LDAP in Liberty Profile

Tags: xml, jakarta-ee, web, ldap, websphere-liberty

I'm trying to connecting LDAP from my loginPage but I always get the errorPage immediately after login. I'm using liberty profile 8.5.5.5 and Eclipse Luna

This is my form

```
<form id="formGeneral" class="centered"  method="post" action="j_security_check"> ....
```

This is my web xml

```
....
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/loginPage.jsf</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>
           GestionArchivosSecurityConstraint
        </web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/pages/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description>
            Sólo usuarios con rol "*" pueden entrar a la aplicación
        </description>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>    
<security-role>
   <role-name>*</role-name>
</security-role>    
<login-config>
  <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
  <realm-name>ldap</realm-name>
  <form-login-config>
    <form-login-page>/loginPage.jsf</form-login-page>
    <form-error-page>/loginPage.jsf?error=true</form-error-page>
  </form-login-config>
</login-config>
.....
```

And this is my server.xml`

```
<ldapRegistry 
    baseDN="DC=rimacdemo,DC=com,DC=pe" 
    bindDN="CN=xxxxxxxxxxx,OU=Cuentas Servicio,DC=rimacdemo,DC=com,DC=pe" 
    bindPassword="xxxxxxxx" 
    connectTimeout="15m" 
    host="xxxxxxxxx" 
    id="ldap" 
    ignoreCase="true" 
    ldapType="Microsoft Active Directory" 
    port="xxx" 
    realm="SampleLdapADRealm" 
    returnToPrimaryServer="false"
    searchTimeout="20m">
</ldapRegistry>
```

And I always get the error page setting in the web.xml configuration
So please someone explain me what does the "j_security_check".. I don't know exactly how it connects with the LDAP to get the error page and I don't know if I'm making the correct configuration

And please, explain me all the meanings of the tags in the web.xml, because I'm reading but I don't understanding the most of the tags.

If someone can help me with the entire flow to follow I'll be more than grateful. I'm only need to authenticate no more than that, I don't need to read properties and don't need to validate groups, only check if the user and password are corrects.

Comment: Add error message from the logs to the post. Did you configure bindings between security roles and users in Liberty (add server.xml)?

Comment: Add full server.xml or at the very least, show the nodes for the deployed application, features added to server, and any related to user registries. Plus, as @Gas said, error messages from the log.